# Can't update from 2.5.3 to 2.5.4 using DevDemon Updater

Tags: devdemon-updater

I'm trying to update a new site I'm developing from 2.5.3 to 2.5.4 and I'm getting a "waiting for server" message and the retry count keeps going up. I've left it to do its thing for a while now and nothing happens. Anyone else seeing this and do you know why it's happening or have a solution to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DevDemon noted yesterday that the file format for EE has changed with the 2.5.4 release and that they'd be working on an update to Updater.

From conversations on Twitter, it looks like EllisLab has changed the format of the the file back, so if you re-download 2.5.4 it should work.

Comment: I didn't try this update until this morning but I did see that tweet. The copy of 2.5.4 I grabbed was fresh off the EL site so I don't see that as an issue.

Comment: Interesting.. might have to contact DevDemon then. I know they'd been working on an update before the file changed.

Comment: Also, revert back to Updater 3.1.6 if you're using 3.1.7

Comment: Actually I am using 3.1.6. Devot-ee Monitor didn't show any updates to Updater when I checked.

Comment: I had no problem this morning updating to 2.5.4 using Updater 3.1.6 so not sure what happened :S

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this happened but I had to move on so I started from a fresh default install and everything worked fine.